# XNA - Where should I start playing a song?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, monogame

I am just wondering where is the best place to start playing the background song for a game. In the loadContent() method, Draw(), or Update() methods or when I initialize it?

I am trying to make it so that the song starts playing at the same time the screen appears.

Answer (score 2):

In "real" XNA is it safe to do so in any of the methods you listed, although **I would recommend `BeginRun`** myself, which is called *once*, immediately before the first call to `Update`.

```
protected override void BeginRun()
{
    MediaPlayer.Play(song);
    base.BeginRun();
}
```

MonoGame has historically implemented the startup sequence with subtle differences to the real XNA. But in this case it's *probably* quite safe to treat it like XNA. (I think at one stage it didn't even have the `BeginRun` method in `Game` - hopefully that's been fixed.)

It's totally reasonable and safe to simply do this:

```
bool songStarted = false;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(!songStarted)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        songStarted = true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Which may seem over-done in this context, but starts to make more sense when you need to have greater control over music playback (eg: starting a song at the beginning of each level).

Finally, you may be tempted to implement the above check by checking the `MediaPlayer.State` property each frame (instead of your own boolean). I strongly recommend **not doing this**, as (at least in XNA) this is a slow, blocking operation that can significantly slow down your game.

Comment: Is it not ok to simply play the song in loadcontent? as this is only called once just before the game is rendered.

Comment: `LoadContent` is ok (like I said - all the methods you listed are ok). But `BeginRun` is more semantically correct.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I am using monogame the the music is played from within a game screen (using screenmanager) so using beginrun might be a bit tricky. But I like to do things properly, so I will have a look.

Comment: The game screen class might provide different methods to `Game`, but they'll ultimately be called from somewhere in `Game` - so that's fine too.